# How can I put images next to the form using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an image next to the form. I tried using `inline-block` and `float` method, but all suggestions I tried just messed up the contents. How can I put the image on the left side of the form?
My code is below:

```css
contactContainer {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}

.contactContainer form {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: left;

}
.contactContainer img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;

}


.buttonHolder {
    text-align: center;
}

input[type=Text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    padding: 12px; /* Some padding */
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 2px; /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}

input[type=Submit] {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
}

input[type=Submit]:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: gray;
}

.twoContainer{
    display: flex;
}    

.twoContainer img {
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="twoContainer">
<img src="images/tour2.jpg" alt="contact image">

<div class="contactContainer">
    <form action="https://formspree.io/lyndall@lyndallwalker.com" method="POST">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Jane Doe">

        <label for="subject">Message</label>
        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder=" " style="height:200px"></textarea>

        <div class="buttonHolder">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another div for the image but taking it out of
The contactContainer div. Then you'll wrap both of them (the image in a new div and the contact container div) in a third div (for example lets call it container). You want to remove the display properties that you have applied and you will give the container div this property

```
.container{
     Display: flex;
 }
```

If the image doesnt size ok you can try giving it a width of 50% and if not you can remove the img tag and apply it as an image background to the image Div.

```
.imagediv {
    Width: 50%;
    Background-image: url("yourimage.png");
 }
```

Something like this should do it

Comment: Hi thank you for the suggestion, I tried the first way, wrapping the image and form with a container and it worked but I have an empty space on the right side. I tried to center everything but didn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Try to give the container Div a margin: auto; and it should align in the center.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set `position: absolute` to `.contactContainer form` and `right:0` You can remove `display: inline-block`. It'll do the trick.
Here

HTML

```
<div class="twoContainer">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581264296947-5a26af1aff18?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="contact image" />
      <div class="contactContainer">
        <form
          action="https://formspree.io/lyndall@lyndallwalker.com"
          method="POST"
        >
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Jane Doe" />

          <label for="subject">Message</label>
          <textarea
            id="subject"
            name="subject"
            placeholder=" "
            style="height: 200px"
          ></textarea>

          <div class="buttonHolder">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
      .contactContainer form {
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
        margin: 30px auto;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: auto;
      }
      .contactContainer img {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 500px;
      }

      .buttonHolder {
        text-align: center;
      }

      input[type="Text"],
      select,
      textarea {
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        padding: 12px; /* Some padding */
        border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Gray border */
        border-radius: 2px; /* Rounded borders */
        box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
        margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
        margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
        resize: vertical; /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
      }

      input[type="Submit"] {
        background-color: gray;
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        align-items: center;
      }

      input[type="Submit"]:hover {
        background-color: white;
        color: gray;
      }

      .twoContainer {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }
```